# How is memory deallocated when Pointers are copied to themselves?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I’ve been getting to writing custom ADTs of all kinds and have recently come across an issue. I figure different languages handle this issue differently, but I'm pretty sure this concept is general, so ill write it in pseudocode.

Say for example, we're working with a custom Array ADT, one that reallocates memory by finding a new, size-appropriate location, and then copying the data over.

We have a method in our ADT that takes a slice of the array and returns a copy of it.

This might look something like this:

```
Arr_ptr = new my_arr[1,2,3,4,5]
.
Arr_ptr_2 = new my_arr
.
Arr_ptr_2 = Arr_ptr.slice(1,3)
```

In this case Arr_ptr_2 would be [2,3,4]

This is fine because the newly copied memory is held by Arr_ptr_2 and the old memory is still owned by Arr_ptr.

However, in a situation like this:

```
Arr_ptr = Arr_ptr.slice(1,3)
```

A new copy of the array is made somewhere else in memory, and ownership of that copy is given to Arr_ptr.

Isn’t the old location in memory now a memory leak, being that nothing is pointing to it anymore? Of course the method slice wouldn’t deallocate the old location because we’re returning a copy, but if it gets assigned to itself, that memory will still exist but no longer have an owner, no?

My background is in C++ so I’m not used to garbage collectors, but I can speculate that a garbage collector would likely see that memory and free it, being that nothing is pointing to it, but in a language without garbage collection, how does one not create a memory leak in this situation?

Thanks

(P.s. I apologize if a question like this has already been asked, It’s not the easiest title to search for :P)

Comment: By "ADT" are you referring to Algebraic Types, or Abstract Types?

Comment: Yes in C++ you're leaking. Even in your first example you leaked what you allocated on the second line. There is a _lot_ of literature about memory management in C++, ever growing. Not using raw pointers for ownership is usually the first step. "RAII" might be a good starting point for research

Comment: "one that reallocates memory by finding a new, size-appropriate location" - it isn't the job of the _array type_ itself to "find" space in memory before filling it, that's the job of the allocator (i.e. the implementation of `malloc`).

Comment: Side note: Before you go too far in this array with slicing capabilities direction, make sure [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) doesn't already do it.

Comment: Re: `the old memory is still owned by Arr_ptr.` and `ownership of that copy is given to Arr_ptr` - raw pointers in C++ do not have concept of "ownership". Smart pointers do.

Comment: You say your background is in C++, but you don't appear to understand how it works at all.

Comment: @OrangeDog not all that uncommon, unfortunately. Far too many people learn C with iostream.

Comment: @OP It seems like you've never used constructors, destructors, copy constructors, and assignment operators, either correctly or understand what their purpose is.